# Specific heat ratio range

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

I know that the specific heat ratio, $\gamma$, exists in the range $1 <\gamma< 2$, and I am required to demonstrate a proof of this.

I have come across the following proof (but I don't really understand it -- or rather, there's something I'm missing):

\begin{equation}
\gamma = \frac{C_{p}}{C_{v}} = \frac{C_{v} + R}{C_{v}} = 1 + \frac{R}{C_{v}} = \frac{C_{p}}{C_{p} - R}
\end{equation}

Where $C_{p}$ is the heat capacity at a constant pressure, and $C_{v}$ is the heat capacity at a constant volume.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1+{R\over C_v}$ is always bigger than 1 as $R$ and $C_v$ are positive. Although I'm not sure you can necessarily put $C_p=C_v+R$, if you *can* then you can probably say that $R<C_v$ so that 
$$
1<1+{R\over C_v}<1+{C_v\over C_v}=2
$$

Comment: Thanks. I believe you can state that, actually. I think it is known as Mayer's relation.